# Simulate Pressing Enter Keys In Safari Using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to simulate the effect of pressing enter key in Safari using Selenium Java.

I have been trying:

```
searchField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

But the enter is not been *hit*. I'm using Selenium 2.39. And safari is 7.0.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: Do you get any error? ho ware you sure that enter is not pressed? What are you trying to achieve with this press of enter?

Comment: Its a search field, with press of enter it search the DB and gives the result. No error are thrown.

Comment: Could you not use searchField.click() ?

Comment: My question is pretty much what @PaulHarris said.  Why do you need to do this?  If your goal is to perform a search, then you should click the submit field, not simulate an enter key press.

Comment: The site doesnt have a search button click. Thats my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this in java

```
 Robot robot= new Robot();
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should first find the element you are trying to hit with enter and then sending the key.